# How many categories are possible with 'n' arrows?

Tags: category-theory

Our professor posed a question in class today -

How many categories are there with 1,2,3 arrows? What about 4,5 and 6?

Isn't the answer two for 2-6 arrows and just one category with one arrow? How does one answer such questions?

Comment: Every object in your category needs an identity arrow. If you define an arrow from A to B and one from B to C you need another from A to C. Does this help?

Comment: @JohnDouma Not quite but I do understand what you are saying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every object has at least one arrow (the identity). So there is only one category with 1 arrow: one object and the identity.

For two arrows: we either have 2 objects (and no more) that both only have the identity (that's 1), or one object $X$ with identity $1_X$ and another arrow $f$. But then either $f \circ f = f$ or $f \circ f = 1_X$ (it has to be one of them, as there are only two arrows). These give distinct categories (I think), so then we have 3 in total.

For 3 arrow we can continue (more cases: 1,2 or 3 objects etc.) It gets quite hairy, I think, for larger numbers of arrows.

Just consider what the axioms force you to have (like identities, and compositions of arrows that are either new or not...).

Updated: found [this presentation](http://www.mta.ca/~gcruttwell/publications/ams2014CruttwellCountingFiniteCats.pdf) that handles the problem in more depth. 6 arrows : 2858 different categories (ouch!)...

Comment: So it would get difficult to tell exactly how many categories form with 6 arrows.

Comment: See the update...

Comment: Thank you so much for the presentation. It was a great help. I have been trying to find something like this but I don't think I was looking at the right place.

Comment: Nice find in the update! I tried searching OEIS to no avail.

Comment: @pjs36 What's OEIS?

Comment: @JAK online encyclopedia of integer sequences. Google it! Fun resource...

Comment: The relevant OEIS page can be found [here](http://oeis.org/A125696), but it doesn't go any further than $n=6$, as already discussed. I believe it counts categories up to isomorphism.